# What is the possibility of finding a shiny Pokemon with a hidden ability in the Kiloude City Friend Safari or horde battles?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

What is the chance of getting a shiny AND a hidden ability Pokemon in Kiloude City Friend Safari or horde battles?

Answer (score 1):

In Generation 6, the chance of encountering a Shiny Pokémon is 1:4096. In horde battles, this works out to be a chance of <strike>5:4096 (ca. 1:819)</strike> **1:819.6**.  1-((x-1)/x)^5

The chance to find a Pokémon with a hidden ability is not fixed (I don't have any information about it, because I didn't play Gen V/VI much and don't know the chance to get the hidden abilities).

The best idea is to catch a male pokemon with the hidden ability and take it in the pension with a ditto. The chance that the hidden ability gets inherited is 60%. So the chance is 1:6827.

- [Horde Encounter](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Horde_Encounter)
- [Hidden Ability](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hidden_Ability#Hidden_Abilities)
- [List of Hidden Abilitys](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_with_released_Hidden_Abilities_%28Generation_V%29)

Comment: If you have a 1/x chance of something happening, and you get 5 tries, your end result is not 5/x. It's 1-((x-1)/x)^5. In this case, it's pretty similar, but it makes a huge difference with smaller x.

Comment: 0,00122010722405363567638625355016 nice number and jet? this is a game forum no math forum pls. Also, you could say the correct value, so I can change it.

Comment: The exact odds are 1406687856537601/1152921504606846976, which works out to about 1/819.6. In this *particular* case, the difference between the two numbers is less than 0.001%.

Comment: @Warterminator I didn't say to just give a number and jet. I just mean if you're going to answer the question then at least use the right method to answer it. You still can and *should* give extra details about what that equation means, how it works, why it's relevant, etc. This is not a forum at all, it's a Q&A site, and when the A requires math (such as a question about statistics), then get the math right, please.

Comment: All happy jet? thx. If someone knew the chance to get a hidden ability pls add it here.

Comment: So the chance of finding shiny pokemon in hordes is 1 in 819.6 and the chance of getting a shiny HA pokemon in hordes is 1 in 6872?If it is,then please adjust your answer like that.

Comment: I can't say whats the chance to get a shiny HA pokémon, because I don't know what's the chance to get a HA pokémon and i can't find any information about it. The 1:6827 is only the chance if you already have a pokémon with a hidden ability and you want to get it in shiny with breeding.

Comment: Thanks for trying but I also want to know the chance of getting HA shiny pokemon in hordes